# Meteor.status() not change on disconnect

Tags: meteor

Meteor.status().status report "connected", also if I disconnect PC (ethX down)

It work only if I close meteor server.

How can I notify if client is connected (or not) to the server?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a while for it to notice, keep in mind the web browser isn't aware of your hardware activities (ethernet disconnected, sudden loss of internet, etc). There are a couple of new APIs out there with HTML5 but meteor doesn't yet use these & they don't work under all browsers.

The only way to tell is to try to connect and watch for errors/failures to connect.

As soon as a heartbeat is missed (not sure what the interval is), or you run a `.call`,`.insert`, etc and there isn't a reply from the server then the status will change to disconnected.

Comment: you have right! but also if I run .call or .insert I have to wait timeout of connection. thanks!

Comment: You don't have to run them, if you do meteor would notice when you want it to. If you just leave it it will also notice (there is a periodic heartbeat/ping every ~30 seconds just to check if the socket is still open). If you check the websocket wire you would see these 'h's

Comment: @AlmogKoren meteor introduced echo like heartbeats in ddp v pre2 and ddp 1. This helps decrease the time it takes to find this has happened. You can decrease it further by decreasing the heartbeat frequency at the cost of a slightly higher server load if it is important to find when your browser/app has disconnected sooner. More info at: https://meteor.hackpad.com/DDP-Heartbeats-jdQy4zGB4Bx